# Can we determine when the lowest-energy state cannot be annihilated by any local operator, just by inspection of the Hamiltonian?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, mathematical-physics, quantum-entanglement, lattice-model

Relativistic quantum field theory (QFT) has the property that the lowest-energy state cannot be annihilated by any operator that is localized in a finite region of space (references 1,2,3). In other words, the lowest-energy state is **separating** for the set of local operators (reference 4). The same property also holds in many other models that are not strictly relativistic. It holds when a relativistic QFT is regulated by discretizing space (Hamiltonian lattice QFT), and it also holds in a wide variety of condensed-matter models. As explained in detail in reference 4, this property can be interpreted is saying that all local subsystems are entangled with each other in the lowest-energy state.

**Question:** By looking at the way the Hamiltonian is expressed in terms of local operators, how can we tell that its lowest-energy state will be separating for all local operators?

---

References:

1. Horuzhy (1990), *Introduction to Algebraic Quantum Field Theory*
2. Witten, *Notes on Some Entanglement Properties of Quantum Field Theory* (https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.04993)
3. Sanders, *On the Reeh-Schlieder Property in Curved Spacetime* (https://arxiv.org/abs/0801.4676)
4. Papadodimas and Raju, *State-Dependent Bulk-Boundary Maps and Black Hole Complementarity* (https://arxiv.org/abs/1310.6335)

Comment: Came here from your other question. Within perturbation theory, the annihilation operator is the integration of the local field operator (or its momenta) over the whole spacelike slicing, i.e. $a_{\omega} = \int_M d^{d-1}x  \phi(x) f_{\omega}(x),$ where $f$ is a smearing function. Note that from the Fourier theorem, one cannot construct $a_{\omega}$ if $f$ doesn't have support on the entire manifold. Even a restriction to a bounded subregion of $M$ would lead to some $a^{\dagger}_{\omega}$ terms as well as other annihilation operators. One can generalize this by taking the support to a point.

Comment: In other words, at least perturbatively I don't think it's a property of the Hamiltonian itself but rather a property of the local operators themselves (apart from the fact that the Hamiltonian can be decomposed as free field + interaction terms). It would be nice if there is a stronger axiomatic proof of this statement, which doesn't depend on details of perturbation theory.

Comment: @BruceLee In strictly nonrelativistic QFT, local operators do exist that annihilate the vacuum state, and we can't tell if a theory is (non)relativistic just from the net of operators at a single time. We need to know the time-dependence. If we know the net of local operators in a finite time-interval, then we have enough information, and then we also implicitly know the Hamiltonian $H$. But (in the canonical formulation) we typically go the other way: we start with operators at one time and then use $H$ to specify their time-dependence. That's why I expressed the question in terms of $H$.